# Passing model through to new action not entirely working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass through model information from one action to another.  This works for the most point but when it translates this to the new action with querystring it doesn't have a querystring parameter for agentopeninghours or agentphonenumber.  These are both strings and if I replace the 'MedicalDataCapture.AgentOpeningHours' with a "3" it works fine.  I have tried encoding the model item, but this doesn't seem to work either.

It must be something simple but I can't see what it is.

Thanks in advance all.

```
        var QuoteSummaryViewModel = new MedicalQuoteSummaryViewModel
        {
            PolicyTransactionNo = Success,
            AgencyRef = MedicalDataCapture.AgencyRef,
            AgentOpeningHours = MedicalDataCapture.AgentOpeningHours,
            AgentPhoneNumber = MedicalDataCapture.AgentPhoneNumber,
            SchemeId = MedicalDataCapture.SchemeId
        };

        //TempData["AgentPhoneNumber"] = QuoteSummaryViewModel;

        return RedirectToAction("QuoteSummary1", QuoteSummaryViewModel);



    public ActionResult QuoteSummary1(MedicalQuoteSummaryViewModel QuoteSummaryViewModel)
    {
```

Comment: Have you debugged and ensured that the model has values for those fields? If hard-coding a string fixes it, that can be the only cause...

Comment: Thanks Ant, going back to basics helped and realised I was losing it between Get and Post of the previous action (was looking in the wrong place).  Dropped it into a hidden field on the form and now working a treat.  Can't believe how long I have been staring at that!!!!

Comment: Related to this, locally it all works but once deployed to Azure it behaves oddly.  /medical/QuoteSummary1?QuoteSummaryViewModel=ConsumerWeb4.ViewModels.MedicalQuoteSummaryViewModel rather than locally which is ?PolicyTransactionNo=fd6d4683-fd1b-4e9d-b615-6ef78ef812d0&AgencyRef=6002&SchemeId=3&AgentPhoneNumber=0845 111 222&AgentOpeningHours=Monday - Friday 9am - 5pm